# KERNEL32 dll dependencies issues

Tags: visual-studio, dll, kernel32

I have a problem loading a dll and by using dependencies walker I found out that there are missing OpenCV dlls which I downloaded and it resolve the openCV issue.

There are still missing dependencies releted to KERNEL32 and I don't know how to fix.

[image: Kernel32.dll missing dependencies]

Comment: which windows do you use? which VS/Win SDK version have you used to compile the code?

Comment: I use windows 10 and VS 2013 update 5

Comment: thus is stil too broad. which win 10 version/Build? What is your platform target configuration in solution properties?